# Page numbering wrong with longtable and captions

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable

I'm attempting to make a product catalog/price sheet. I am using longtable, since it's not uncommon for tables to span more than 1 page. Everything works great, but it seems when a longtable starts on a page, but then is forced to the next page to fit at least 1 row, the counter does not increment. For example, Tools - Corona - Pruner shows page 6 on the TOC, but appears on page 7. I ran latex 6 or 7 times on the code. Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass[8pt]{report}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \usepackage{everypage}
    \usepackage[space]{grffile}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

    \hypersetup{%
        pdfborder = {0 0 0}
    }
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
    \end{minipage}\par}%

    \lfoot{\today}
    \rfoot{\thepage}
    \cfoot{}
    \rhead{}
    \lhead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \captionsetup{labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=off,labelformat=empty,labelfont=bf}
    %
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
    \makeatother
    %


    \newif\ifimportant\importantfalse

    \AddEverypageHook{
        \global\importanttrue
    }

    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.80}
    \definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

    \begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength\unitlength{1in}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    \huge
    {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Product Catalog}\\
    \vspace{.25in}
    {\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont DOUG PETERSON}\\
    \vspace{.25in}
    {\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont \today}

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large www.mountainlandsupply.com}

    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}

    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Turf}
    \markboth{Turf}{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Bar}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Bar}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Bar}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Bar}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        272858 & BR 70090 & BR 70090 14LB SAN ANGELO DIGGING BA & \$45.56 ea\\\hline
                6705 & BR 73090 & BR 73090 18LB 60IN PINCH POINT BAR & \$68.34 ea\\\hline
                345490 & BR 74090 & BR 74090 32LB 69IN LANDSCAPE BAR & \$113.89 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Broom}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Broom}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Broom}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Broom}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        6718 & BM 60001 & BM 60001 18" LANDSCAPE BROOM WD 60IN WOOD HANDLE & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
                415576 & BM 61002 & BM 61002 CORONA PUSHBROOM 2 BRISTLES & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
                271547 & BM 62060 & BM 62060 24IN PUSH BROOM ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$63.72 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        379120 & 42000-8 & 42000-8 CORONA CUTTER MATTOCK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
                6746 & PM 42000 & PM 42000 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
                345488 & PM 75020 & PM 75020 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK FBR 36IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Extractor}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Extractor}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Extractor}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Extractor}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        383115 & UT 65001 & UT 65001 EZ OUT - 1IN AND 1-1/4IN STEEL BODY WITH ZINK HEAD & \$15.95 ea\\\hline
                383116 & UT 65002 & UT 65002 EZ OUT - 1/2IN AND 3/4IN STEEL BODY WITH ZINK HEAD & \$8.59 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - File}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - File}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - File}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - File}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        476446 &  & 4 IN 1 FILE AND RASP & \$17.94 ea\\\hline
                476459 & FR410108BC1CD & CORONA HALF ROUND WOOD RASP & \$21.51 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Hammer}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hammer}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hammer}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hammer}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        68742 & ST 43003 & ST 43003 3LB DRILLING HAMMER WD 10IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$25.75 ea\\\hline
                272050 & ST 70021 & ST 70021 8LB SLEDGEHAMMER FBR 32IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$50.55 ea\\\hline
                236113 & ST 70024 & ST 70024 12LB SLEDGEHAMMER FBR 32IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$65.29 ea\\\hline
                345454 & ST 73003 & ST 73003 3LB DRILLING HAMMER FBR 10IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$28.33 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Handles}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Handles}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Handles}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Handles}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        347760 & 41000-4 & 41000-4 HANDLE - POLY GURARD FOR PICKS AND MATTOCKS & \$32.36 ea\\\hline
                271638 & 73020-4 & 73020-4 HANDLE - SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS FOR PICKS \& MATTOCKS & \$33.33 ea\\\hline
                272958 & AX 70020 & AX 70020 3-1/2LB MICHIGAN AXE FBR 34IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$62.23 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Hoe}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hoe}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hoe}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Hoe}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        288263 & SH 60060 & SH 60060 6IN GARDEN HOE ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$36.77 ea\\\hline
                311823 & SH 60061 & SH 60061 - 6IN OSCILLATING HOE ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$40.43 ea\\\hline
                288500 & SH 63000 & SH 63000 - 7IN HEAVYDUTY WEEDING HO 60IN ASH WOOD HANDLE & \$41.68 ea\\\hline
                423317 & SH 65000 & SH 65000 CORONA MCLEOD HOE 48IN ASH WOOD HANDLE & \$68.61 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Lopper}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Lopper}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Lopper}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Lopper}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        6876 & AL 8260 & AL 8260 32" HD LOPPER - 2 1/4" CUT & \$79.33 ea\\\hline
                235823 & AL 8462 & AL 8462 2-1/4IN CUT ORCHARD LOPPER 32IN ALUMINUM HANDLES & \$74.44 ea\\\hline
                6886 & FL 3470 & FL 3470 1-5/8IN CUT BYPASS LOPPER 21-33IN EXTENDABLE FBR HANDLES & \$36.05 ea\\\hline
                6871 & SL 3310 & SL 3310 24" BYPASS LOOPER - 1 1/2" CUT & \$35.21 ea\\\hline
                345492 & SL 7180 & SL 7180 2IN CUT DUAL BYPASS LOPPER 31IN STEEL HANDLES & \$58.70 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Misc}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Misc}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Misc}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Misc}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        237376 & AC 7220 & AC 7220 5IN LEATHER SCABBARD W/ CLIP AND BELT LOOP & \$14.82 ea\\\hline
                345501 & AC 7310 & AC 7310 18IN MACHETE SCABBARD FOR MA60041 & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
                237184 & AC 8300 & AC 8300 SHARPENING TOOL & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
                347529 & AH 4220 & AH 4220 COMPOUND ACTION HEDGE SHEAR 9IN BLADE 11IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$26.70 ea\\\hline
                417592 & AS 90400 & AS 90400 WIRE \& EDGING TRENCHER CORONA & \$75.69 ea\\\hline
                345493 & CT 3010i & CT 3010I COMFORT TROWEL POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$6.48 ea\\\hline
                276140 & CT 3020I & CT 3020I COMFORT TRANSPLANTER POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$6.11 ea\\\hline
                345494 & CT 3030i & CT 3030I COMFORT CULTIVATOR POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$0.00 ea\\\hline
                288588 & FK 72065 & FK 72065 5 TINE MANURE FORK ALUM 54IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$67.39 ea\\\hline
                345491 & HS 3070 & HS 3070 7IN PRECISION HEDGE SHEAR POLY HANDLES & \$21.85 ea\\\hline
                229709 & HS 7140 & HS 7140 10IN DUAL CUT HEDGE SHEAR ALUMINUM HANDLES & \$49.50 ea\\\hline
                345498 & MA 60041 & MA 60041 18IN MACHETE CO-MOLDED HDL & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
                345499 & MA 61040 & MA 61040 14IN CANE KNIFE WOOD HANDL & \$9.11 ea\\\hline
                235421 & PD 40020 & PD 40020 - POST HOLE DIGGER FBR HDL 12GA 48IN FIBERGLASS HANDLES & \$55.14 ea\\\hline
                415583 & SG 2950 & SG 2950 CORONA BULB PLANTER ** DISCONTINUED AS OF 6-15-2015 ** & \$4.38 ea\\\hline
                235700 & UT 20000 & UT 20000 1/2 MOON EDGER 48IN WD HDL & \$25.92 ea\\\hline
                278273 & UT 66004 & UT 66004 - 4IN HEAD TRIMMER 29IN SHAFT W/ T-HANDLE \& GRIPS & \$49.01 ea\\\hline
                360095 & UT 66006 & UT 66006 6IN HEAD TRIMMER CORONA & \$61.25 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Pick}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pick}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pick}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pick}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        379118 & 40000-8 & 40000-8 CORONA RAILROAD PICK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
                379119 & 41000-8 & 41000-8 CORONA PICK MATTOCK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
                271926 & PM 40000 & PM 40000 5LB RAILROAD PICK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
                272032 & PM 41000 & PM 41000 5LB PICK MATTOCK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
                236099 & PM 73020 & PM 73020 5lb RAILROAD PICK FBR HNDL 36IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline
                6739 & PM 74020 & PM 74020 5LB PICK MATTOCK FBR 36IN SOLID CORE FBR HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Post Driver}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Post Driver}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Post Driver}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Post Driver}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        6796 & UT 67001 & UT 67001 2-1/2IN POST DRIVER & \$107.81 ea\\\hline
                6805 & UT 67003 & UT 67003 2-1/2IN POST DRIVER 65IN LONG REACH MODEL & \$103.66 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Pouch}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pouch}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pouch}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pouch}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        237451 & AC 4510 & AC 4510 6-3/4IN NYLON TOOL POUCH & \$10.34 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Pruner}

    \begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
        \caption{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pruner}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pruner}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{\textbf{Tools - Corona - Pruner}}\\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        6902 & BP 3160 & BP 3160 3/4" BYPASS PRUNER RADIAL ARC BLADE / ALL STEEL & \$27.92 ea\\\hline
                6893 & BP 3180 & BP 3180 1" BYPASS PRUNER RADIAL ARC BLADE / ALL STEEL & \$32.76 ea\\\hline
                415571 & TP 3811 & TP 3811 CORONA 10FT TREE PRUNER & \$65.52 ea\\\hline
                347505 & TP 6830 & TP 6830 - 12FT TREE PRUNER DUAL COMPOUND ACTION POWERGLIDE ROPE PULL SYSTEM & \$98.94 ea\\\hline
                237002 & TP 6850 & TP 6850 14FT TREE PRUNER DUAL COMPOUND ACTION CHAIN PULLEY SYSTEM & \$100.00 ea\\\hline

    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tools - Corona - Pruner}` is read on page 6; it has nothing to do with the last `longtable`.  `\caption` generates entries in `\listoftables` which you don't use.

Comment: Trying to understand your comment. So is your suggestion to not use the \addcontentsline command, but instead rely on the \listoftables command to generate the TOC?

Comment: I recommend not to \`abuse' `\addcontentsline` to generate a table of contents.  I suggest to use `\chapter`, `\section` etc. and customize them acc. to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat use of TeX and LaTeX! :-)

The `\addcontentsline` directives *precede* `\begin{longtable}`, and the two directives aren't guaranteed to be executed on the same page. Since the table formats are all the same for all longtables, except for the caption, it's handy to create a macro that (a) contains all the table header instructions and (b) places the `\addcontentsline` instruction *after* `\caption` (the first instruction after `\begin{longtable}`). Doing so lets you remove a lot of repetitive stuff from the body of the document.

Specifically, you could set up a macro named `\tableheader`, which contains all the formatting instructions and takes one argument -- the caption:

```
\newcommand\tableheader[1]{%
\begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
\caption{#1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{#1, continued}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endhead}
```

Note that I've eliminated the duplicate material prior to `\endfirsthead`.

The full document, then, would be generated by the following code:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=off,
          labelformat=empty,font=bf}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \usepackage{everypage}
    \usepackage[space]{grffile}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
    \end{minipage}\par}%

    \lfoot{\today}
    \rfoot{\thepage}
    \cfoot{}
    \rhead{}
    \lhead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    %
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
    \makeatother
    %


    \newif\ifimportant\importantfalse

    \AddEverypageHook{
\global\importanttrue
    }

    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.80}
    \definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

    \usepackage{url}
    \urlstyle{sf}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=black}


\newcommand\tableheader[1]{%
\begin{longtable}{p{.625in}p{1.5in}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}
\caption{#1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{#1}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
\hline
\endhead}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength\unitlength{1in}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \centering

    \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Product Catalog\par
    \vspace{.25in}
    \fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont DOUG PETERSON\par
    \vspace{.25in}
    \fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont \today\par

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    \large \url{www.mountainlandsupply.com}
    \normalsize
    \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}

    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Turf}
    \markboth{Turf}{}

\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Bar}
272858 & BR 70090 & BR 70090 14LB SAN ANGELO DIGGING BA & \$45.56 ea\\\hline
6705 & BR 73090 & BR 73090 18LB 60IN PINCH POINT BAR & \$68.34 ea\\\hline
345490 & BR 74090 & BR 74090 32LB 69IN LANDSCAPE BAR & \$113.89 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Broom}
6718 & BM 60001 & BM 60001 18" LANDSCAPE BROOM WD 60IN WOOD HANDLE & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
415576 & BM 61002 & BM 61002 CORONA PUSHBROOM 2 BRISTLES & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
271547 & BM 62060 & BM 62060 24IN PUSH BROOM ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$63.72 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}
379120 & 42000-8 & 42000-8 CORONA CUTTER MATTOCK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
6746 & PM 42000 & PM 42000 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
345488 & PM 75020 & PM 75020 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK FBR 36IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Extractor}
383115 & UT 65001 & UT 65001 EZ OUT - 1IN AND 1-1/4IN STEEL BODY WITH ZINK HEAD & \$15.95 ea\\\hline
383116 & UT 65002 & UT 65002 EZ OUT - 1/2IN AND 3/4IN STEEL BODY WITH ZINK HEAD & \$8.59 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - File}
476446 &  & 4 IN 1 FILE AND RASP & \$17.94 ea\\\hline
476459 & FR410108BC1CD & CORONA HALF ROUND WOOD RASP & \$21.51 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Hammer}
68742 & ST 43003 & ST 43003 3LB DRILLING HAMMER WD 10IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$25.75 ea\\\hline
272050 & ST 70021 & ST 70021 8LB SLEDGEHAMMER FBR 32IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$50.55 ea\\\hline
236113 & ST 70024 & ST 70024 12LB SLEDGEHAMMER FBR 32IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$65.29 ea\\\hline
345454 & ST 73003 & ST 73003 3LB DRILLING HAMMER FBR 10IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$28.33 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Handles}
347760 & 41000-4 & 41000-4 HANDLE - POLY GURARD FOR PICKS AND MATTOCKS & \$32.36 ea\\\hline
271638 & 73020-4 & 73020-4 HANDLE - SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS FOR PICKS \& MATTOCKS & \$33.33 ea\\\hline
272958 & AX 70020 & AX 70020 3-1/2LB MICHIGAN AXE FBR 34IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$62.23 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Hoe}
288263 & SH 60060 & SH 60060 6IN GARDEN HOE ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$36.77 ea\\\hline
311823 & SH 60061 & SH 60061 - 6IN OSCILLATING HOE ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$40.43 ea\\\hline
288500 & SH 63000 & SH 63000 - 7IN HEAVYDUTY WEEDING HO 60IN ASH WOOD HANDLE & \$41.68 ea\\\hline
423317 & SH 65000 & SH 65000 CORONA MCLEOD HOE 48IN ASH WOOD HANDLE & \$68.61 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Lopper}
6876 & AL 8260 & AL 8260 32" HD LOPPER - 2 1/4" CUT & \$79.33 ea\\\hline
235823 & AL 8462 & AL 8462 2-1/4IN CUT ORCHARD LOPPER 32IN ALUMINUM HANDLES & \$74.44 ea\\\hline
6886 & FL 3470 & FL 3470 1-5/8IN CUT BYPASS LOPPER 21-33IN EXTENDABLE FBR HANDLES & \$36.05 ea\\\hline
6871 & SL 3310 & SL 3310 24" BYPASS LOOPER - 1 1/2" CUT & \$35.21 ea\\\hline
345492 & SL 7180 & SL 7180 2IN CUT DUAL BYPASS LOPPER 31IN STEEL HANDLES & \$58.70 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Misc}
237376 & AC 7220 & AC 7220 5IN LEATHER SCABBARD W/ CLIP AND BELT LOOP & \$14.82 ea\\\hline
345501 & AC 7310 & AC 7310 18IN MACHETE SCABBARD FOR MA60041 & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
237184 & AC 8300 & AC 8300 SHARPENING TOOL & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
347529 & AH 4220 & AH 4220 COMPOUND ACTION HEDGE SHEAR 9IN BLADE 11IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$26.70 ea\\\hline
417592 & AS 90400 & AS 90400 WIRE \& EDGING TRENCHER CORONA & \$75.69 ea\\\hline
345493 & CT 3010i & CT 3010I COMFORT TROWEL POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$6.48 ea\\\hline
276140 & CT 3020I & CT 3020I COMFORT TRANSPLANTER POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$6.11 ea\\\hline
345494 & CT 3030i & CT 3030I COMFORT CULTIVATOR POLISHED ALUMINUM ALLOY & \$0.00 ea\\\hline
288588 & FK 72065 & FK 72065 5 TINE MANURE FORK ALUM 54IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$67.39 ea\\\hline
345491 & HS 3070 & HS 3070 7IN PRECISION HEDGE SHEAR POLY HANDLES & \$21.85 ea\\\hline
229709 & HS 7140 & HS 7140 10IN DUAL CUT HEDGE SHEAR ALUMINUM HANDLES & \$49.50 ea\\\hline
345498 & MA 60041 & MA 60041 18IN MACHETE CO-MOLDED HDL & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
345499 & MA 61040 & MA 61040 14IN CANE KNIFE WOOD HANDL & \$9.11 ea\\\hline
235421 & PD 40020 & PD 40020 - POST HOLE DIGGER FBR HDL 12GA 48IN FIBERGLASS HANDLES & \$55.14 ea\\\hline
415583 & SG 2950 & SG 2950 CORONA BULB PLANTER ** DISCONTINUED AS OF 6-15-2015 ** & \$4.38 ea\\\hline
235700 & UT 20000 & UT 20000 1/2 MOON EDGER 48IN WD HDL & \$25.92 ea\\\hline
278273 & UT 66004 & UT 66004 - 4IN HEAD TRIMMER 29IN SHAFT W/ T-HANDLE \& GRIPS & \$49.01 ea\\\hline
360095 & UT 66006 & UT 66006 6IN HEAD TRIMMER CORONA & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Pick}
379118 & 40000-8 & 40000-8 CORONA RAILROAD PICK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
379119 & 41000-8 & 41000-8 CORONA PICK MATTOCK *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
271926 & PM 40000 & PM 40000 5LB RAILROAD PICK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
272032 & PM 41000 & PM 41000 5LB PICK MATTOCK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
236099 & PM 73020 & PM 73020 5lb RAILROAD PICK FBR HNDL 36IN SOLID CORE FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline
6739 & PM 74020 & PM 74020 5LB PICK MATTOCK FBR 36IN SOLID CORE FBR HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Post Driver}
6796 & UT 67001 & UT 67001 2-1/2IN POST DRIVER & \$107.81 ea\\\hline
6805 & UT 67003 & UT 67003 2-1/2IN POST DRIVER 65IN LONG REACH MODEL & \$103.66 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Pouch}
237451 & AC 4510 & AC 4510 6-3/4IN NYLON TOOL POUCH & \$10.34 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\tableheader{Tools - Corona - Pruner}
6902 & BP 3160 & BP 3160 3/4" BYPASS PRUNER RADIAL ARC BLADE~\slash\ ALL STEEL & \$27.92 ea\\\hline
6893 & BP 3180 & BP 3180 1" BYPASS PRUNER RADIAL ARC BLADE~\slash\ ALL STEEL & \$32.76 ea\\\hline
415571 & TP 3811 & TP 3811 CORONA 10FT TREE PRUNER & \$65.52 ea\\\hline
347505 & TP 6830 & TP 6830 - 12FT TREE PRUNER DUAL COMPOUND ACTION POWERGLIDE ROPE PULL SYSTEM & \$98.94 ea\\\hline
237002 & TP 6850 & TP 6850 14FT TREE PRUNER DUAL COMPOUND ACTION CHAIN PULLEY SYSTEM & \$100.00 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now that is awesome!  SO much cleaner and simpler, and appears to fix my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach without using `\caption`.  It uses `titlesec.sty` and `titletoc.sty` to customize the appearance of table of contents and the sectioning commands.  The command `\turfhead` controls the longtables headings.  It uses `\nameref*{<subsec.name>}` for cont. captions.  If you want to revise the name of  the products, you only need to edit the `\subsection` commands and the rest is updated accordingly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable,helvet}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\captionsetup{labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=off,labelformat=empty,labelfont=bf}

\usepackage[pagestyles,nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\sectiontitle}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\subsectiontitle}{0em}{}

\usepackage{titletoc,ragged2e}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]
  {\addvspace{0.3pc}\bfseries\filright}
  {}{\hspace*{0em}}
  {\mdseries\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]
  {\addvspace{0.1pc}\filright}
  {}{\hspace*{0em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\contentspage}

\newcolumntype{T}{%
  p{.625in}p{1.5in}>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{2.75in}p{.875in}}

\newcommand*\turfhead[1]{%
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries #1 \itshape (cont.)}\\\hline
  \rowcolor{Gray} Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \rowcolor{Gray} Product\# & Model\# & Description & Price\\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.80}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Turf}
\subsection{Tools - Corona - Bar}
\label{sec:tools-corona-bar}

\begin{longtable}{T}
  \turfhead{\nameref*{sec:tools-corona-bar}}
  272858 & BR 70090 & BR 70090 14LB SAN ANGELO DIGGING BA & \$45.56 ea\\\hline
  6705 & BR 73090 & BR 73090 18LB 60IN PINCH POINT BAR & \$68.34 ea\\\hline
  345490 & BR 74090 & BR 74090 32LB 69IN LANDSCAPE BAR & \$113.89 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\subsection{Tools - Corona - Broom}
\label{sec:tools-corona-broom}

\begin{longtable}{T}
  \turfhead{\nameref*{sec:tools-corona-broom}}
  6718 & BM 60001 & BM 60001 18" LANDSCAPE BROOM
                    WD 60IN WOOD HANDLE & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
  415576 & BM 61002 & BM 61002 CORONA PUSHBROOM
                      2 BRISTLES & \$61.25 ea\\\hline
  271547 & BM 62060 & BM 62060 24IN PUSH BROOM
                      ALUM 60IN ALUMINUM HANDLE & \$63.72 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\subsection{Tools - Corona - Cutter Mattock}
\label{sec:tools-corona-cutter}

\begin{longtable}{T}
  \turfhead{\nameref*{sec:tools-corona-cutter}}%
  379120 & 42000-8 & 42000-8 CORONA CUTTER MATTOCK
                     *HEAD ONLY* & \$22.78 ea\\\hline
  6746 & PM 42000  & PM 42000 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK WD 36IN HICKORY WOOD
                    HANDLE & \$55.89 ea\\\hline
  345488 & PM 75020 & PM 75020 5LB CUTTER MATTOCK FBR 36IN SOLID CORE
                      FIBERGLASS HANDLE & \$57.78 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\subsection{Tools - Corona - Extractor}
\label{sec:tools-corona-extr}

\begin{longtable}{T}
  \turfhead{\nameref*{sec:tools-corona-extr}}%
  383115 & UT 65001 & UT 65001 EZ OUT - 1IN AND 1-1/4IN STEEL BODY
                      WITH ZINK HEAD & \$15.95 ea\\\hline
  383116 & UT 65002 & UT 65002 EZ OUT - 1/2IN AND 3/4IN STEEL BODY
                      WITH ZINK HEAD & \$8.59 ea\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clever approach. The solution offered by Mico is a bit simpler to convert to from my current code, but I always like learning new techniques that can serve me in the future. Thanks for going above and beyond!